# Start using netbeans for website development

Tags: netbeans, ide

Quite a while ago I used to use eclipse (or actually Aptana) for making websites. I never really got how it worked. After my laptop crashed I decided to install netbeans hoping it would be less complex, however it is still overwhelming. I know that working with a good IDE can help out a lot, but I just find it very complex (steep learning curve).

Does anybody know a few good tutorials to help me get started with this?

BTW I will be using it mostly for building websites (php, html, css) occasionally in a more abstract way (drupal) or using a framework (Zend). However I have done some Java programming and would like to start building some apps for android or maybe even learn c# or c++ for windows 8.

I would also like to start using subversion and if possible an integrated ftp client.

Help to get me started would really be appreciated.

Comment: Netbeans provides suite of tutorials for usage http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/quickstart.html. Please use google before posting to stack. Netbeans provides plugins for subversion and i belive ftp as well

Answer (score 1):

Wow, thats really about 5 different questions. Firstly the benefit of using an IDE (for web development) is generally for refactoring tools, a good text editor, built in web previews and a built in development server like apache or glassfish. For your purposes eclipse and netbeans will work equally well, but I suppose netbeans has a slightly less steep learning curve but both are fairly straight forward. I'm going to give you a list of links that I think will help you:

Netbeans - http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/quickstart.html

Android - http://developer.android.com/training/index.html

Windows bassed svn client - http://tortoisesvn.net/

Free SVN repository hosting - https://www.assembla.com/home

Good FTP client - http://filezilla-project.org/

I don't think there are any combined svn and ftp clients, and it doesn't really make sense to have one either. A quick note on android development that may steer your choice of IDE, Android development is generally done within eclipse using the ADT plugin. Just a few thoughts...